# C# Plugin options

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins

So I'm making a plugin for Visual Studio that opens Internet Explorer and goes to a specified website.
How can I make it so that you can right click the button or something and bring up options and enter in a new URL that is then saved? Not sure how I can do this!
Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried using app.config settings file for your plugin that will save the user settings locally?

Comment: legrandviking is correct.  You get basic appSettings functionality with a custom plugin.  Note, I had trouble with a "config section handler" with a custom plugin, but that was 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: @legrandviking Could you expand on that at all? Really not sure how I would do it. New to it all

Comment: Created a full answer with basics for you. Hoping this will help you on your quest for user settings.

Comment: @legrandviking Thanks for that! Still need a bit of help with allowing the user to edit it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new setting at design time by using the Settings designer. The Settings designer is a grid-style interface that allows you to create new settings and specify properties for those settings. You must specify Name, Value, Type and Scope for your new settings. Once a setting is created, it is accessible in code.

In Solution Explorer, expand the Properties node of your project.
Double-click the .settings file in which you want to add a new setting. The default name for this file is Settings.settings. In the Settings designer, set the Name, Value, Type, and Scope for your setting. Each row represents a single setting.

How to read settings
Via the Properties.Settings.Default member. 
The following example shows how to assign myName setting to a string Name property.

```
this.Name = Properties.Settings.Default.myName;
```

How to write settings

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myName = "Robert"
```

If you want to persist the changes to the settings between application sessions, call the Save method, as shown below:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Thanks very much that helps me. The only thing I'm wondering now is, since this is a plugin I'm making, and the user has no access to the source code, how can I make the website editable? Is there some sort of plugin settings they can go to and see the settings for the plugin and change it there or what?

Comment: I suggest you create an admin section for the website protected by username and password. There you can have forms that deal with updating settings through a simple html form